# Best performance- and backup-strategy with running multiple Webapps and databases on dedicated servers

Tags: backup, performance, database, dedicated-server, web-applications

my company is soon going to move our webservice-hosting to a new hoster and therefore i'm currently planing how everything will run in the future.

I have to deploy at least:

- MsSQL-Database Server storing our products and sales. Quite high traffic.
- The MsSQL-Database will come with some .net Applications.
- Our public-accessible webshop. PHP 5.6 + mysql
- Our internal webapplications. PHP 7 + mysql

I plan to rent one or two dedicated servers for that.
So my main question is: How will i get the best performance for my pool of applications and databases and whats the best backup-strategy for them?
Should I put every application and database into a V-Server? How will that decrease performance?

One Idea I had:
[Link to my server-plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKsuB.png)
Important here is the backup on allways the other Dedicated server in case one somehow loses its data.

Any Suggestions are wellcome.
Thanks in Advance

-Paul

Comment: welcome to SF Paul, you should try to break down your question into multiple specific ones that illustrate your thinking and concerns. it is <b>very</b> broad.

Comment: Allright. I see that. Maybe my final question should have been a bit lighter. Something like "Should I virtualize on a Dedicated server in this special case. Performance and Backup-related"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fool-proof strategy you can try proxmox, so you virtualize your dedicated server and can take advantage of kvm virtualization if planning to use Windows os, or lxc for recent linux distro. Then you can easily snaphot each VM into external ftp/nfs + some 'ol good file level backup (attic backup, acronis, rsync, rsnapshot, rdiff backup, bacula, and so on). In future, if you use drbd or hi speed nfs or iscsi shared storage you could opt for proxmox high availability clustering

Comment: Thanks!

As simple as the answer seems it helped me with my desicion.
Snapshots are a huge argument for virtualization imo.

Comment: @user103675 if you are ok, please accept my anawer :)